# Hebrew calendar in python

Tags: python, calendar

I have to work with Jewish Calendar in Python. 
I want to know if there is a Jewish Calendar in Python or if there is import in python

Hope for answers

Comment: Have you searched Google? https://www.google.com/search?q=hebrew++calendar+python

Comment: @Blender: Ironically, that exact search brings me to this page as the first result.

Answer (score 7):

You could use [the Python Date Utilities module](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pythondateutil/), which claims to convert between different date systems, including Hebrew.

There is more info on this site ([Jewish calendar calculation in Python](http://www.david-greve.de/luach-code/jewish-python.html)), which covers the manual implementation of some utilities such as the calculation of Jewish holidays and the weekly Torah sessions.

Comment: Unfortunately, david-greve's site that you linked to is no longer maintained, and does not support Python 3.

Answer (score 5):

[pyluach](https://github.com/simlist/pyluach) makes it trivial to transform Jewish dates to Gregorian and vice-versa.
It also has the Weekly Torah Reading (Parasha), but does not have Jewish Holidays.